# Stopping Vmmem from using RAM

Tags: windows, docker

I am using Docker to run some containers on Windows 10, and when I was done I noticed an application named vmmem was using almost all of my ram: ~12GB. According to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180717-00/?p=99265#:%7E:text=The%20vmmem%20process%20is%20a,of%20memory%20and%20CPU%20resources.) it is because of Docker and it said if I closed all docker images and containers it would stop. So I stopped and removed all Docker containers and images by the following batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker ps -aq') DO docker rm %%i
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker images --format "{{.ID}}"') DO docker rmi %%i
```

from: https://gist.github.com/daredude/045910c5a715c02a3d06362830d045b6

so when you type `docker container ls -a` & `docker image ls -a` they both show nothing. However in Task Manager I still see vmmem using about 4 GB of RAM. What else can I do to stop this? Thanks.

Comment: You running windows Linux subsystem WSL1 or WSL2?

Comment: @PaulWhelan W2L

Comment: Wondering if these is an issue with W2L: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166, disappointing they can't make something work that is so widely used...

Comment: "We've turned on autoMemoryReclaim=dropCaches by default for the latest WSL version and updated the inactivity time to 10 minutes to help with this issue. This will make WSL by default return its used memory after 10 minutes of inactivity."  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166#issuecomment-1961544948

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I found the simplest and easiest way to shut down Vmmem is to go into Windows powershell / cmd and enter: `wsl --shutdown`. This shuts it down.

Comment: actually this is the only answer, terminating even all of distributions won't free up RAM :|
and they say Linux is lightweight. maybe Microsoft reserve so much RAM on purpose. cause Linux was actually lightweight

Comment: Similarly, wsl --shutdown alone does not solve the problem. It frees up some memory for sure, but the actual solution is to create .wslconfig and restart the service as described in collage-code's response.

Comment: @HassanFaghihi Terminating distributions worked for me (Windows 10). https://i.imgur.com/9Bg6ScN.png

Comment: Occasionally when quitting Windows Terminal the vmmem process continues in the background with high CPU. This answer solved it.

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: @bobi And what if wmmem is still running after using wsl --shutdown?

Comment: This worked perfectly on Win10, instantly from 100% CPU to 15%. Nice!

Comment: I tried this command once and it hung forever. The only way I could figure out how to solve the problem was to restart my whole computer and then run it.

Comment: it was a running docker instance in my case

Comment: This command hangs and does nothing for me((

Comment: In my case `wsl --shuwdown` did the trick. But quite annoying that I can't run an instance without it taking over my resources. In my case it was 4GB ram AND 20% CPU. Shutting down the process and restarting freed up CPU, though.

Answer (score 79):

Create a `%UserProfile%\.wslconfig` file, and add the following configuration to it:

```
[wsl2]
memory=6GB # How much memory to assign to the WSL2 VM.
processors=5 # How many processors to assign to the WSL2 VM.
```

Note: by default, memory is 50% of total memory on Windows or 8GB, whichever is less, and processors is the total number available.

Then restart WSL2, by running the following command in PowerShell (running as Administrator):

```
Restart-Service LxssManager
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18945 and https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig

Comment: This limits the amount of memory and processors, but this doesn't fix my issue of stopping them completely when they are not being used.

Comment: For me, wsl --shutdown and then Restart-Service LxssManager made the vmmem process quit and return the allocated memory. This response is really what should be marked as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 27):

to check out all running distros on your WSL

```
wsl -l -v
```

to terminate the ones in use

```
wsl -t {insert distro}
```

more here
https://blog.simonpeterdebbarma.com/2020-04-memory-and-wsl/

Comment: This worked, though I had to shut down the distros several times until the memory usage finally went down from 11GB to nothing. It was a gradual freeing of memory too, took about a minute to deflate all the way down.

Answer (score 17):

Simplest way to shut down Vmmem and to save restarting your machine, run below command in CMD or PowerShell as administrator:

```
taskkill /F /IM wslservice.exe
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this way

1. open start menu -> find 'Hyper-V Manager' just by typing
2. stop the virtual machine -> right-click -> turn off (look at the picture)

[image]

Comment: This answer actually worked for me. Thanks,

Comment: Nothing is showing up for me here, even though wsl says Linux and docker desktop are running.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I found out long forgotten broken Multipass managed Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when I installed docker and realized it was using a lot of ram even when I was not using docker at that moment.

To mitigate this I had to disable docker auto startup such that I only use it when needed instead of auto-starting and running in the background even when not being used:-

1. Open the Docker panel and go to settings, disable start docker desktop when u log in. The docker vmem process will not auto start next. it will start when you open docker.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue.

Go to `Docker Desktop > Settings > Software updates` 
Then **uncheck** the box: Automatically check for updates

[image]

I don't know how its related but it works

For more info, visit: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12266

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run > Type "services"

Find docker and click stop

[image: Right Click Menu for Docker Desktop Service in Services Window with Stop hovered]

Comment: This did nothing to `vmmem`'s memory usage. In fact, `wsl -l -v` still says: `openSUSE-42 Running and docker-desktop Running`.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug unique to windows 10 which or may not have to do with a going in and out of sleep. See https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12944

As long as the WSL2/Docker Desktop combo hasn't completely frozen you can do the following

```
wsl -d docker-desktop /bin/sh -c "free -h;sync; sleep 5; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;sleep 1; free -h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while reinstalling docker desktop. I tried -

- Removing docker dekstop.
- Restarting the windows 11 machine
- Shutdown from powershell

Finally what worked for me was -

- Open taskmanager.
- Go to process details
- Stop process starting with vm
  You may receive some warnings but go ahead.

Restarted the machine. Reinstalled docker desktop. Again restarted    the machine. Voila docker desktop is working again

IMHO the issue is related to disk backup software. Even after removal of certain files such software brings them back.